# Verificar se canvas esta desenhado

Tags: javascript, canvas

Olá.
Preciso de alguma função para verificar se meu canvas foi desenhado pelo usuário.
O código é o seguinte:

```
    <canvas id="canvas">
        Este navegador não suporta esta função.
    </canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var start = function(coors) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(coors.x, coors.y);
        this.isDrawing = true;
    };
    var move = function(coors) {
        if (this.isDrawing) {
            context.strokeStyle = "#000";
            context.lineJoin = "round";
            context.lineWidth = 3;
            context.lineTo(coors.x, coors.y);
            context.stroke();
        }
    };
    var stop = function(coors) {
        if (this.isDrawing) {
            this.touchmove(coors);
            this.isDrawing = false;
        }
    };
    var drawer = {
        isDrawing: false,
        mousedown: start,
        mousemove: move,
        mouseup: stop,
        touchstart: start,
        touchmove: move,
        touchend: stop
    };
    var draw = function(e) {
        var coors = {
            x: e.clientX || e.targetTouches[0].pageX,
            y: e.clientY || e.targetTouches[0].pageY
        };
        drawer[e.type](coors);
    }
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchend', draw, false);

    var go = function(e) {
            draw(e);
        }
    };

    document.getElementById('divCanvas').addEventListener('mousedown', go, false);
    document.getElementById('divCanvas').addEventListener('touchstart', go, false);

    // prevent elastic scrolling
    document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
    // end body:touchmove
    window.onresize = function(e) {
        canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
        canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
    };



    $('.aviso2').click(function(){
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    });

    </script>
```

O usuário pressiona o mouse ou o touch e vai desenhando seguindo o seu comando. Eu preciso de alguma função para verificar se o usuário realmente desenhou no canvas. Preciso ver se o canvas não está em branco.

Já tentei utilizar uma leve gambiarra pra isso. Quando o usuário clica o mouse ou o touch, eu incremento uma variável com o tempo que ele está segurando o clique/mouse. Assim no final, eu faço um if pra ver se esse tempo foi menor que 5 segundos por exemplo. Se for, é por que ele não desenhou ou desenhou incorretamente (só rabiscou qualquer coisa rapida).

Há como?

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer? Poderia adicionar à pergunta?

Comment: Claro, vou adicionar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determinar se é vazio é "complicado", pelo simples fato que a pessoa pode desenhar algo em "branco", ou desenhar algo que fique fora da área visivel, ainda sim encontrei esta resposta no SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17386803/1518921

A primeira sugestão é do [@AustinBrunkhorst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/818182/austin-brunkhorst) usando [**`getImageData`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) para buscar os pixels "não colorizados", ficando algo como:

```
function isCanvasBlank(canvas) {
  return !canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data.some(function (channel) {
      return channel !== 0;
   });
}
```

Outra sugestão do [@Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386707/how-to-check-if-a-canvas-is-blank/17386803#comment96825186_17386803) que afirma que pode ser mais rápido enumerar sob o  [**`Uint32Array`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint32Array) do que percorrer cada canal de cores em cada pixel:

```
function isCanvasBlank(canvas) {
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const pixelBuffer = new Uint32Array(
    context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data.buffer
  );

  return !pixelBuffer.some(function (color) {  return color !== 0 });
}
```

Não sei se de fato melhora, pois seria que repassar o *buffer*, mas talvez se de fato a imagem for muito grande poderá sentir alguma vantagem

---

Forma lenta:

```
function isCanvasBlank(canvas) {
  const blank = document.createElement('canvas');

  blank.width = canvas.width;
  blank.height = canvas.height;

  return canvas.toDataURL() === blank.toDataURL();
}
```

Eu não creio que essa forma seja só lenta, creio que ela seja ineficiente, mesmo o `toDataURL` retornando resultados parecidos para algo vazio ainda sim pode ocorrer variações, ainda mais se tiver algo que "polui" injetado com `putImageData()` ou `drawimage()` mas é "invisível"

---

### Sobre a pergunta especifica

Você citou isto

> Se for, é por que ele não desenhou ou desenhou incorretamente (só rabiscou qualquer coisa rapida).

Mas é complicado afirma o que é um rabisco, uma ideia que eu tive seria usar o `getImageData()` e calcular quantos pixels são diferentes de `0` determinando um limite máximo de "100" (é um exemplo) que podem ser diferentes, isto é um código hipotético não cheguei a testar:

```
function CanvasAlmostEmpty(canvas)
{
      const pixelBuffer = new Uint32Array(
        context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data.buffer
      );

      const limite = 100;

      return pixelBuffer.filter(function (color) {
           return color !== 0;
      }).length <= 100;
}
```

No exemplo do código ficou assim, ele filtra com `.filter` quantas cores são diferentes do "vazio" e então com `.length` saberemos quantos pixels temos coloridos na área, com `.length <= limite` checamos se passou do limite, ajuste esta linha para determinar o limite:

```
 const limite = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma é verificar através dos eventos `mousedown` e `mousemove` (`touchstart` e `touchmove` para dispositivos de toque).

Imagine o seguinte: quando o usuário clica na área do canvas, irá disparar o evento `mousedown`, se ele soltar o clique, irá disparar o evento `mouseup`, ok? No evento `mouseup` irá chamar a função `stop`. Porém, o usuário pode simplesmente clicar no canvas e soltar o click do mouse sem desenhar nada. O que determina que algo foi desenhado é se ele clicou no canvas e, sem chamar o `stop` (evento mouseup), ele mover o mouse (com o botão do  mouse clicado).

A forma que encontrei foi fazendo essa verificação com 3 variáves:

```
var existe,     // se algo foi desenhado
    mouseDown,  // se clicou no canvas
    mouseMove;  // se moveu o mouse no canvas
```

Quando algo tiver sido desenhado, a variável `existe` será alterada para `true`, e a mesma coisa para as variáveis `mouseDown` e `mouseMove`.

Em relação às duas últimas variáveis, utilizei dois `if`'s dentro da função `draw`:

```
if(e.type == "mousedown" || e.type == "touchstart") mouseDown = true;
if( (e.type == "mousemove" || e.type == "touchmove") && mouseDown) mouseMove = true;
```

O primeiro `if` detecta um dos dois eventos, `mousedown` e `touchstart`, e altera a variável `mouseDown` para `true`. Se logo em seguida for disparado os eventos `mousemove` ou `touchmove`, e a variável `mouseDown` é `true` eu altero a variável `mouseMove` também para `true`.

Na função `stop` eu tenho outro `if` que verifica se a variável `mouseMove` é `false`. Se for `false`, significa que aqueles dois `if`'s na função `draw` não foram satisfeitos, logo eu deixo a variável `mouseDown` como `false`:

```
if(!mouseMove) mouseDown = false;
```

Na mesma função `stop`, tenho um segundo `if` que verifica se as duas variáveis, `mouseDown` e `mouseMove`, são verdadeiras, significando que algo foi desenhado no canvas, e muda a variável `existe` para `true`:

```
if(mouseDown && mouseMove) existe = true;
```

Até aqui tudo bem, porém existe um erro no seu código quando usado em dispositivos touch (pelo menos no iPhone testado aqui): no evento `touchend`, a propriedade `e.targetTouches` fica vazia, gerando exceção em `e.targetTouches[0].pageX` e `e.targetTouches[0].pageY`.

Por isso coloquei um `if` para tratar especialmente esse evento, guardando em duas variáveis as últimas coordenadas `X` e `Y` e passando esses valores para o objeto `coors`.

Veja o código abaixo como ficou e teste-o tanto no desktop quanto num dispositivo touch:

```js
var existe, mouseDown, mouseMove;

function verifica(){
   if(existe){
      alert("Algo foi desenhado");
   }else{
      alert("Nada!");
   }
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var start = function(coors) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(coors.x, coors.y);
        this.isDrawing = true;
    };
    var move = function(coors) {
        if (this.isDrawing) {
            context.strokeStyle = "#000";
            context.lineJoin = "round";
            context.lineWidth = 3;
            context.lineTo(coors.x, coors.y);
            context.stroke();
        }
    };
    var stop = function(coors) {
        if (this.isDrawing) {
            this.touchmove(coors);
            this.isDrawing = false;
            if(!mouseMove) mouseDown = false;
            if(mouseDown && mouseMove) existe = true;
        }
    };
    var drawer = {
        isDrawing: false,
        mousedown: start,
        mousemove: move,
        mouseup: stop,
        touchstart: start,
        touchmove: move,
        touchend: stop
    };
    var draw = function(e) {
       if(e.type != "touchend"){
        var coors = {
            x: e.clientX || e.targetTouches[0].pageX.toString(),
            y: e.clientY || e.targetTouches[0].pageY.toString()
        };
        
        var lastX = coors.x;
        var lastY = coors.y;
       }else if(e.type == "touchend"){
        var coors = {
            x: lastX,
            y: lastY
        };
       }
        drawer[e.type](coors);
         if(e.type == "mousedown" || e.type == "touchstart") mouseDown = true;
         if( (e.type == "mousemove" || e.type == "touchmove") && mouseDown) mouseMove = true;
    }
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchend', draw, false);

    var go = function(e) {
            draw(e);
        }
//    };

//    document.getElementById('divCanvas').addEventListener('mousedown', go, false);
//    document.getElementById('divCanvas').addEventListener('touchstart', go, false);

    // prevent elastic scrolling
    document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
    // end body:touchmove
    window.onresize = function(e) {
        canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
        canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
    };



    $('.aviso2').click(function(){
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    });
```

```css
body{
margin: 0;
}

#canvas{
   height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas">
   Este navegador não suporta esta função.
</canvas>
<br>
Desenhe na área acima<br>
<button onclick="verifica()">Verifica se há desennho</button>
```